# managing multiple foreign_key in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am struggling to build a good schema/associations between models in Rails, and hope for some advice. A "player" has multiple "picks", and each "pick" is made up of three "riders", ordered.

Summarizing the schema:

```
create_table players do |t|
  t.string "name"
  ...
end

create_table picks do |t|
  t.integer "player_id"
  t.integer "rider1_id"
  t.integer "rider2_id"
  t.integer "rider3_id"
  ...
end

create_table riders do |t|
  t.string "name"
  ...
end
```

I have some of the associations between the models built up:

```
player.rb:
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks
end

pick.rb:
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :riders, :foreign_key => "rider1_id"
  has_many :riders, :foreign_key => "rider2_id"
  has_many :riders, :foreign_key => "rider3_id"
  belongs_to :player
end

rider.rb
class Rider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pick
end
```

I feel/know that I am missing some basic understanding of associations in the code above. In particular, I would like to be able to say something like: "myPick.rider1.name". I would also be able to look at which picks include a given rider, like "myRider.picks" (though I am not sure this is even possible). And fundamentally, I am not sure it's the right idea to have three "rider" foreign keys in the pick model.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Cheers,
Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your association a bit backwards. The table with the foreign key `belongs_to` the table without. So you should have 3 `belongs_to :rider1, :class => 'Rider'` calls in place of those `has_many` calls.

```
# player.rb:
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks
end

# pick.rb:
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rider1, :class => 'Rider'
  belongs_to :rider2, :class => 'Rider'
  belongs_to :rider3, :class => 'Rider'
  belongs_to :player

  def riders
    # returns an array so you can say pick.riders.each { |rider| ... }
    # but it doesn't give you an ActiveRecord::AssociationProxy so you cannot 
    # do things like pick.riders.where(:condition => true)
    [rider1, rider2, rider3]
  end
end

# rider.rb
class Rider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :pick
end
```

This still isn't going to be as clean as doing a `has_many :riders` and enforcing a limit on the number of riders for each pick (using the built-in relationships as intended).

Comment: Thank you. Fundamentally, I had the wrong syntax for `belongs_to`. I had to slightly modify what you wrote above (perhaps because I am still using Rails 2 - legacy project), but I got it to work with: `belongs_to :rider1, :class_name=>'Rider', :foreign_key=>:rider1_id`. I also really like the idea of the `riders` method, and being able to manipulate all the riders from one array. Thanks so very much!